# Custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, post, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type and it is working fine. Is there a way that we can distribute a custom post type in two parts for example when we register the post type it usually show this in the dashboard. All Products, Add new, categories. These three options are shown and when we click on add new then we enter data.I want this that their should also be add new 2 in the same menu. Some fields are shown in the add new and some shown in the add new 2. 
**Is this scenario possible in word press**. If **yes** then please help me out how can i do this. I have searched a lot but nothing found yet.

Comment: Wordpress does not provide this functionality yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, then yes its possible.

You would need to have 2 custom post types and use metaboxes.

Here is handful generator tools:
**Custom posts Generator** - http://fooplugins.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/

**Metaboxes generator** - http://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-meta-box-generator/ 
(in post types set "custom" instead of "post" and type your custom post name).

as for merging 2 custom posts types under one menu in admin - please read [Group Custom Post Types in one menu Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480031/group-custom-post-types-in-one-menu-wordpress) solution.